# std::unordered_map segmentation fault in constructor

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I've been getting a strange segmentation fault when allocating objects that have unordered_map as an atribute, the debug seems to point to it happening somewhere over at hashtable.h when allocating the map. Anyone know why this happens?

i reaches a value of 13222438 before the segmentation fault.

```
struct Graph{
    unordered_map<int,Graph*> neighbor;
    int something(){return (int)neighbor[0]++;///so it doesnt get optimized out
    }
};
int main(){
    std::list<Graph*> test;
    for(long long i=0; i< 100000000.0d;i++ ){
        test.push_back(new Graph());
    }
    std::cout<< "Done" <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case it should be a complete compilable program.

Comment: If you need to construct such a huge list just to show a memory related error, you are probably just running out of it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

When I adjust your program to actually compile, and build it in 64-bit mode, it completes fine.

When I build it in 32-bit mode, it does with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

because it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly running into system memory limitations.

On my system, `sizeof(Graph)` is 56. It will take about 5 GB of memory to create `100000000` of just the objects. Of course, there are other overheads associated with dynamic memory allocation and creating a list of pointers.

I am to able to run the program in my environment when creating `10000000` objects, 10 times less than the number you are using, but the crashes if I add another zero to the end of that number.